# Adding an image (in code) in order show an image on the view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

I have this quiz application where the user is presented with a question and four options. The options are within a table view function and the label is changed via code for each question. I would like to add image based questions. I have some images in my asset but when I try

image.UIImageView this is an error.

I would like it so that when the new question and answers are called up by the user, a new image is presented in the image view.

Here is the code, as well as a provided screenshot of the view controller.

---

```
import UIKit

class imagequizpage1: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    
    var gameModels = [Question]()
    
    var currentQuestion: Question?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        setupQuestions()
        configureUI(question: gameModels.first!)
        
    }
    
    private func configureUI(question: Question) {
    label.text = question.text
    currentQuestion = question
    table.reloadData()
    }
    
    private func checkAnswer(answer: Answer, question: Question) -> Bool{
        return question.answers.contains(where: { $0.text == answer.text }) && answer.correct
    }
    
    
    private func setupQuestions(){
    gameModels.append(Question(text: "What is this image", answers: [
        Answer(text: "A bridge", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "A waterway.", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "A skyline", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "A park", correct: false)
    ]))
        
        
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentQuestion?.answers.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = currentQuestion?.answers[indexPath.row].text
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    guard let question = currentQuestion else {
        return
    }
    
    let answer = question.answers[indexPath.row]
    
    if checkAnswer(answer: answer, question: question) {
        // correct
        if let index = gameModels.firstIndex(where: { $0.text == question.text }) {
            if index < (gameModels.count - 1){
                // next question
                let nextQuestion = gameModels[index + 1]
                currentQuestion = nil
                configureUI(question: nextQuestion)
            
                }
                else{
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Done", message: "You beat the game" , preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    present(alert, animated: true)
                }
           }
        }
        else{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong", message: "That's wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        
}

    struct Question {
        let text: String
        let answers: [Answer]
}

    struct Answer {
        let text: String
        let correct: Bool
}
}
```

---

[[image: the view controller presentation1]

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set image to imageView

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Asset Name")
```

Note: change your `UIImageView` name ... instead of `image` use `imageView`

Comment: Ok! The code works, however when a new question is brought up, the image does not change but stays the same. Is this due to the placement of the code within the function? An answer would be greatly received! Thanks!

Comment: Where you are changing image ?

Comment: There are a 'series' of questions, so the -gameModels.append(Question(text: ... ), answer: ])) is repeated for each 'new question'. I am not sure where to place the code within this, as, if it is outside of the function then the image does not change.